# EASYEDA "Auto Router is already running or address is already in use" Issue

Tags: pcb-design, autorouter

Why do I get this error message every time? I don't have it open, I've restarted my computer several times and it still gives me error messages.

(Self-answered below, including Auto Router port issues, Local Auto Router, Remote Auto Router, and Docker info.)

Answer (score 0):

### The issue seems to be caused by a port exclusion conflict. I have seen some people say that this can be due to docker or Hyper-V conflicts.

I couldn't post this on the EASYEDA Forum because of

> special words, block by the server

so here I am.

I've had this problem many times and finally decided to fix it in a more robust way. Now I have done a few extra things for my own convenience, but I'll start with a basic resolution.

Run this in CMD.exe as Administrator to see your current Port Exclusion Ranges:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

You'll notice that one of the lines probably looks like this and which describes a range of 3501-3601 and contains our port 3579:

### To allow Auto Router to run, we need to add port 3579 as an excluded port range. To do so, we must first stop `winnat`, then add the exclusion, and and finally start `winnnt`.

1. Run this in CMD.exe as Administrator to stop `winnat`**(This will probably disconnect your Internet, do be alarmed)**:

```
net stop winnat
```

2. Run this in CMD.exe as Administrator to add the 3579 exclusion:

```
netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=3579 numberofports=1
```

3. Run this in CMD.exe as Administrator to start `winnat`:

```
net start winnat
```

---

### Now onto the fancy stuff. If you want to run the Auto Router on a different computer, you will need to setup a port proxy.

To do this you will need to know the IP of the destination computer.

1. Get the IP of the Auto Router computer. This can be done with `ipconfig` for Windows and `ifconfig` for most Linux distros.
2. Run this in CMD.exe as Administrator **(be sure to replace the connectaddress value with the Auto Router computer's IP)**:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3579 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=3579 connectaddress=<remote-ip>
```

---

Lastly, I decided to put the Auto Router in a docker for convenience. I used the [openhoangnc/easy-eda-router](https://hub.docker.com/r/openhoangnc/easy-eda-router) image. It's fairly straightforward.

This is not required at all, but to change the Auto Router port, open the Auto Router archive or zip found [here](https://docs.easyeda.com/en/FAQ/Download/) and navigate to `.\EasyEDA-Router-latest\config\local\main.json` , open it with notepad.exe or the text editor of your choice, and change the `"port": 3579,`line to the port you desire.